# How to disabling checkboxes inside recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have list/rows of checkboxes inside recycle view. In my case, the user can only select 3 checkboxes out of many. As soon as the user selects the third checkbox, I want to disable rest of the checkboxes in different rows.

I am capturing selecting/deselecting checkboxes inside `adapter` class.

As far as I know, I can enable/disable checkboxes inside `onBindViewHolder` class.

But in my case, I want to enable/disable checkboxes, after they have been rendered.

One of the approaches I can think is, to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` from Activity class and then rerender all the recycled view.

But I hope there is the better way than doing this, inside the adapter class itself.

ps: I am new to android/java.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` will defently work in your case.

Please note that you don't have to call this method from the Activity. 
You can call it internally within your adapter after the third checkbox was selected.

From the top of my head, One way to do this would be to store the "checked" positions indide an array within the adapter, then inside `onBindViewHolder()` check to see if the current position should be enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your model class you can have a boolean variable that decide whether the item should be enabled or not and another boolean variable to keep track of the checked state, or if the item is checked or not. In `onBindViewHolder` check the variable to enable or disable the item.Keep track of the selected items and then after every check and uncheck, check if the selected items exceeds the limit. Then loop through your items and then check if the item is checked or not. if the item is not checked set the value to false and after the loop send a `notifyDataSetChanged()` and in `onBindViewHolder()` check for the value and enable or disable the item/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to record all the changes for each item based on their positions.

You can use the following method in **RecyclerView** adapter:

```
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
```

Read more at [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

Only use `notifyDataSetChanged()` as the last resort. Because calling notifyDataSetChanged() will force the views to rebind and relayout. As in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) says:

> void notifyDataSetChanged ()
>
> Notify any registered observers that the data set has changed.
>
> There are two different classes of data change events, item changes
> and structural changes. Item changes are when a single item has its
> data updated but no positional changes have occurred. Structural
> changes are when items are inserted, removed or moved within the data
> set.
>
> This event does not specify what about the data set has changed,
> forcing any observers to assume that all existing items and structure
> may no longer be valid. LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind
> and relayout all visible views.
>
> RecyclerView will attempt to synthesize visible structural change
> events for adapters that report that they have stable IDs when this
> method is used. This can help for the purposes of animation and visual
> object persistence but individual item views will still need to be
> rebound and relaid out.
>
> If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use
> the more specific change events if you can. Rely on
> notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.